# ionic installation issue: xmlbuilder

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

cant get ionic to setup and run because of the xmlbuilder error and have tried every possibilty of trying it but no luck:

C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules>ionic start todo blank

Error: Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (C:\Users\armaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:12:13)
    at Object. (C:\Users\armaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:436:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install -g xmlbuilder
```

just this!

hope that helps ;)

Comment: Actually as an argument.